# d3js scale, transform and translate

Tags: d3.js

I've created [nycMap](https://github.com/climboid/nycMap), a project that uses angularJS (MVC), yeoman (build), d3 (mapping) and geoJSON (geo data).

Everything works very nicely, but I did have to spend quite some time getting the right scale and translation. I was wondering how I can automatically figure out at what scale the map will show its best and what x and y values go into the translation?

```
'use strict';

japanAndCo2App.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

 function makeJapanAll(){
    var path, vis, xy;

    xy = d3.geo.mercator().scale(16000).translate([-5600,2200]);
    path = d3.geo.path().projection(xy);
    vis = d3.select("#japanAll").append("svg:svg").attr("width", 1024).attr("height", 700);
    d3.json("data/JPN_geo4.json", function(json) {
      return vis.append("svg:g")
          .attr("class", "tracts")
          .selectAll("path")
          .data(json.features).enter()
          .append("svg:path")
          .attr("d", path)
          .attr("fill",function(d,i){ return d.properties.color || "transparent"});
    });
  }
  makeJapanAll();
});
```

(If you are interested in the code, it's all [on github](https://github.com/climboid/nycMap). The code for the map is in [scripts/controllers/main.js](https://github.com/climboid/nycMap/blob/master/app/scripts/controllers/main.js) which is the same as shown above.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've had the same problems. But it is very easy to do when you have a bounding box, which can be determined from the GeoJSON (like meetamit said), or while creating the GeoJson. And the width of the wanted SVG.

I'll start with the variables `lattop, lonleft, lonright, width` and `height` for the bounding box of the geojson and the dimensions of the image. I haven't yet occupied myself with calculating a good height from the difference in latutude. So the height is just estimated to be big enough to fit the image. The rest should be clear from the code:

```
var xym = d3.geo.mercator();

// Coordinates of Flanders
var lattop = 51.6;
var lonleft = 2.4;
var lonright = 7.7;
var width = 1500;
var height =1000;

// make the scale so that the difference of longitude is 
// exactly the width of the image
var scale = 360*width/(lonright-lonleft);
xym.scale(scale);

// translate the origin of the map to [0,0] as a start, 
// not to the now meaningless default of [480,250]
xym.translate([0,0]);

// check where your top left coordinate is projected
var trans = xym([lonleft,lattop]);
// translate your map in the negative direction of that result
xym.translate([-1*trans[0],-1*trans[1]]);


var path = d3.geo.path().projection(xym);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width",width).attr("height",height);
```

Note, if you go over the date line (180 degrees), you will have to take the overflow into account.

Comment: Hey sanderd17 thanks for your comment. I had not though about the bounding box, this looks quite cool. Will give it a shot.

Comment: This is not working for me. I am using d3.geo.albers(). Does the code depend on the projection? Which coordinates do I have to use for the bonding box? I think I am using the projected coordinates...

Comment: With albers, it should work 'almost' I guess. It's possible that a part of the image will be out of the svg bounds, but the biggest part should be visible. Can you show me the coordinates you used, and say which region you're working in?

Answer (score 8):

Given this:

```
xy = d3.geo.mercator().scale(someScale).translate([0, 0]);
```

`someScale` is **the pixel width** of the **entire world when projected** using the mercator projection. So, if your json data had outlines for the whole world – spanning from lat/lng -180,90 to latLng 180,-90 – and if `someScale` was 1024, then the world would be drawn such that it exactly fits within a 1024x1024-pixel square. That's what you see on in [this Google Maps view](https://maps.google.com/?ll=-0.35156,0.351563&spn=163.944564,10.898438&t=m&z=2) (well... sort of... not quite... read on...).

That's not enough though. When the world is drawn at 1024px, without any translation, lat/lng 0,0 (i.e. the "middle" of the world) will sit at the 0,0 pixel of the projected map (i.e. the top left). Under these conditions, the whole northern hemisphere and western hemisphere have negative x or y values, and therefore fall outside the drawn region. Also, under these conditions, the bottom right of the world (i.e. lat/lng -90, 180) would sit at the exact middle of the 1024x1024 square (i.e. at pixel 512,512).

So, in order to center the world in the square described here, you need to `translate` the map by half its width in the X and Y directions. I.e. you need

```
xy = d3.geo.mercator().scale(1024).translate([512, 512]);
```

That'll give you exactly the Google Map view I linked to.

If your json data only has part of the world (like, nyc or NY state) drawing it with this xy projection will render the outlines in the correct geographic position relative to the entire 1024x1024 world-spanning region. So it would appear rather small, with lots of whitespace.

The challenge is how to scale and translate the projection such that the area in question fills up the 1024x1024 square. And... so far I haven't answered this question, but I hope that this explanation points you in the right direction towards figuring out this math. I'll also try to continue the answer later, when I have more time.   :/

Comment: Any luck so far? I downloaded your github project (also bc I wanted to try out yeoman). Pretty cool. Your latest commit has NY state map, not nyc, but doesn't matter. I tried to figure out the math for framing it like you'd want to, but it turned out trickier than I expected. I managed to calculate the bounds of the area being framed very easily, using `d3.geo.bounds(json)`, but the scaling and translation still elude me. Also @Lars-Kotthoff's links provide some direction, which at first glance looks different than what I had been trying.

Comment: Yeah so far the only recipe I've found is starting with a scale of 100, you'll get a small dot and then scale up and translate at the same time in jumps of 200.. .takes about 10 mins to get it just right depending on how big you want the map...asking @jasondavies to see if he has a clue.

Answer (score 0):

There's an example [here](http://www.larsko.org/v/igdp/) that gets the bounds of countries from geojson and then scales and translates the map to that country. The code is a bit ugly; there're however efforts to make this easier in the future (see [this](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/pull/330) and [this issue](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/pull/846)).

Comment: Thanks for sharing lars. I saw that at the end Mike mentioned  "d3.geo.projection center (and rotate)" which I guess will take care of this issue on v3?