# Translating and Scaling map to fit the viewport in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, gis, geojson

I am trying to load a map of Rio de Janeiro (Brazil) in GeoJson for with D3js

the code and the map is here:
https://gist.github.com/4157853

I can open the map normally with Qgis, but with d3js nothing appears in the SVG canvas.
My projection is epsg4326, the same as google maps. and the units are in lat/long.

What am I doing Wrong?

Comment: Can you verify (using "inspect element") that the appropriate `path`s for Rio de Janeiro are being created (just drawn really small). If so, then this should help you fix it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274151/d3js-scale-transform-and-translate/13277197#13277197

Comment: meetamit my paths look like this:<path d="MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZ">

Comment: Clearly something is being lost when loading the geojson, I'll look into it...

Comment: it is very strange because my geojson looks just fine
   {"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[-43.39632541627463, -22.83185052736464], [-43.39462012443045, -22.830266754507672]...